# Can I hold two locks simultaneously with Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, locking

The current locking concept of my application assumes to get hold of 2 locks and perform code. But I always get an error when I try to release the first lockhandle. Is there a way to do this or am I wrong using dbms_lock to get 2 locks at one time?

Best regards!

```
DECLARE
  l_handle_1 VARCHAR2(128);
  l_handle_2 VARCHAR2(128);
  l_result NUMBER;
BEGIN

    -- >>> LOCK1
    dbms_lock.allocate_unique('lock_1', l_handle_1);
    l_result := dbms_lock.request(l_handle_1, dbms_lock.x_mode, 10, true);
    BEGIN

      -- >>> LOCK2
      dbms_lock.allocate_unique('lock_2', l_handle_2);
      l_result := dbms_lock.request(l_handle_2, dbms_lock.x_mode, 10, true);
      BEGIN

        /*
         * PLSQL-Code with both locks held
         */

        -- LOCK-2 release
        l_result := dbms_lock.release(l_handle_2);
        IF (l_result > 0) THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('Fail 2');
        END IF;

        -- LOCK-1 release
        l_result := dbms_lock.release(l_handle_1);
        IF (l_result > 0) THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('Fail 1');
        END IF;

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          l_result := dbms_lock.release(l_handle_2);
          IF (l_result > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Fail 3');
          END IF;
          RAISE;          
      END;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        l_result := dbms_lock.release(l_handle_1);
        IF (l_result > 0) THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('Fail 4');
        END IF;
        RAISE;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: Just to make sure (it might not be relevant in your case): You are not trying to synchronize the data access for concurrent sessions as one would synchronize parallel threads in a shared memory application? It wouldn't work because of transaction isolation and other major differences in architecture.

Comment: Thread synchronization is the main goal, yes. May you have a small hint where I could find information why this is not possible?

Comment: Oracle sessions do not directly share data structures and on Unix/Linux they aren't threads but processes. They mainly share data in tables. However, if they change a data row in a table, it is hidden from other sessions until it's committed. This is called transaction isolation. Simple updates are synchronized by default. If you update lots of rows, you might want to use SELECT FOR UPDATE or change the transaction isolation to the stricter SERIALIZABLE mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you call dbms_lock.request with release_on_commit = TRUE  for the first lock handle and then call allocate_unique. 
allocate_unique performs a commit and hence releases the first lock.

You will not get an error if you change you code as follows:

```
DECLARE
  l_handle_1 VARCHAR2(128);
  l_handle_2 VARCHAR2(128);
  l_result NUMBER;
BEGIN


    dbms_lock.allocate_unique('lock_1', l_handle_1);
    dbms_lock.allocate_unique('lock_2', l_handle_2);

    -- >>> LOCK1
    l_result := dbms_lock.request(l_handle_1, dbms_lock.x_mode, 10, true);
    BEGIN

      -- >>> LOCK2
      -- dbms_lock.allocate_unique('lock_2', l_handle_2);
      l_result := dbms_lock.request(l_handle_2, dbms_lock.x_mode, 10, true);
      BEGIN

        /*
         * PLSQL-Code with both locks held
         */

        -- LOCK-2 release
        l_result := dbms_lock.release(l_handle_2);
        IF (l_result > 0) THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('Fail 2');
        END IF;

        -- LOCK-1 release
        l_result := dbms_lock.release(l_handle_1);
        IF (l_result > 0) THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('Fail 1');
        END IF;

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          l_result := dbms_lock.release(l_handle_2);
          IF (l_result > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Fail 3');
          END IF;
          RAISE;          
      END;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        l_result := dbms_lock.release(l_handle_1);
        IF (l_result > 0) THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('Fail 4');
        END IF;
        RAISE;
    END;
END;
```